# How to alter a column by adding UNIQUE

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I would like to alter a column without the addition of constraint:

My column definition:

```
...  
name character varying(64) not nul,
...
```

What I want:

```
...
name character varying(64) unique not nul,
...
```

I tried:

```
alter table T add unique(name);
```

but a constraint with index is suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table T add constraint unique_name unique (name);
```

See the examples in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Or as part of the table definition:

```
create table t
(
   ...,
   name character varying(64) not null,
   constraint unique_name unique (name)
);
```

Or simply as a unique index:

```
create unique index unique_name on t (name);
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs suggest:

```
alter table T add unique using index I
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html

This would assume you've created the unique index I beforehand.